# Cocos2d-x how to create image button with title and font

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-x, game-engine

Hi i am converting my game from Corona SDK to Cocos2d-x 3.0 alpha.

I need to create an image button with text on it. It was very simple in Corona SDK with `widget.newButton`, which takes all `x, y, size, font, image` etc in single function.

Now i couldn't find any alternate to this in Cocos2d-x. The closest thing i have found in it is `MenuItemImage`

```
auto closeItem = MenuItemImage::create(
                                    "blank.png",
                                    "blank-selected.png",
                                     CC_CALLBACK_1(HelloWorld::menuCloseCallback, this));

closeItem->setPosition(Point(origin.x + visibleSize.width - closeItem->getContentSize().width/2 , origin.y + closeItem->getContentSize().height/2));

auto menu = Menu::create(closeItem, NULL);
menu->setPosition(Point::ZERO);
this->addChild(menu, 1);
```

It takes the `images` and `event`, but i cannot set `title` and `font` on it. Anyone has idea how to set title and font on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `MenuItemFont` or `MenuItemLabel`.

For example:

```
MenuItemFont::setFontName( "Marker Felt" );
MenuItemFont::setFontSize( 34 );

auto label = LabelBMFont::create( "go back", "fonts/bitmapFontTest3.fnt" );
auto back = MenuItemLabel::create(label, CC_CALLBACK_1(MenuLayer4::backCallback, this) );
```

or

```
MenuItemFont::setFontSize( 34 );
MenuItemFont::setFontName("Marker Felt");
auto item6 = MenuItemFont::create("Bugs", CC_CALLBACK_1(MenuLayerMainMenu::menuCallbackBugsTest, this));
```

For more information, see [`MenuTest.ccp`](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/cocos2d-x-3.0alpha0/samples/Cpp/TestCpp/Classes/MenuTest/MenuTest.cpp)

---

**update**

You can simply new a Label, and add it to you `MenuItemImage`, such as:

```
LabelTTF* closeLabel = LabelTTF::create("close", "Marker Felt", 28);
closeItem->addChild(closeLabel);
```

And you may need to adjust the label's position.

Comment: thanks for reply, but how to set image in this example? According to my question, i need a way to create a an image with title and font on it. I have created a "blank" image, that needs to be used through out the app. I just have to add title on it with code.

Comment: so you mean i need to create LabelTTF and MenuItemImage separately and adjust positions for both?

Comment: Thanks @pktangyue, i am having another problem. Can you look into it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139335/cocos2d-x-background-image-is-not-displaying-properly

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple, this works in at least cocos2d-x 3.10 and 3.16, but if you're looking to make a button with cocos2d, use the built in `cocos2d::ui` namespace for `Button`.

```
cocos2d::ui::Button* button = cocos2d::ui::Button::create();
//button textures
button->loadTextures(
        "<your default texture>.png",
        "<your pressed texture>.png",
        "<your disabled texture>.png",
        cocos2d::ui::Widget::TextureResType::PLIST
    );

//text content, font, and size
button->setTitleText("Touch me!");
button->setTitleFontName("arial");
button->setTitleFontSize(24.0f);

//bind a callback with a lambda
auto touch_handler = [](cocos2d::Ref* ref, cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType evt)
{
    if (evt == cocos2d::ui::Widget::TouchEventType::ENDED)
    {
        //do your callback logic here, ie play a sound or vibrate
    }
};
button->addTouchEventListener(touch_handler);

//then finally, like a Nodes, add it to your scene
my_scene->addChild(button);
```

The textures you'll load are ideally packed into a texture with something like TexturePacker, otherwise you'll change it to `LOCAL` instead of `PLIST`. The textures will be used when the button is default, or when there's a touch, or when the button is disabled.