# Cocos2d-x Background image is not displaying properly

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-x, game-engine

i am new to `Cocos2dx 3.0 alpha` and converting my game from `Corona SDK` to `Cocos2d-x 3.0 alpha`.
I am displaying a background image like this.

```
auto sprite = Sprite::create("bg.png");
sprite->setPosition(Point(visibleSize.width/2 + origin.x, visibleSize.height/2 + origin.y));
this->addChild(sprite, 0);
```

But the image is distorted in iOS simulator. I also get these 3 warnings in console. May be 1 warning for each image, as i am displaying 3 images.

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

Here are the screen shots.
[image]

This is the actual image.
[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think it is because your `bg.png` is not well supported by libpng. You may try another way to export the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is because your bg.png dimension's ratio does not match with your designResolutionSize ratio. Your bg.png has a dimension of 512x256 while iphone screen has 480x320. So I assume that you set your design resolution size to that of iphone (480x320) hence your background image is not displaying properly. Try changing the design resolution size to the size of your bg.png or resize your bg.png to match your design resolution size. For more info about design resolution size and/or multi resolution support visit this wiki page: [click me](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Multi_resolution_support)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @jonah1none, thanks for reply. After changing resolution to 480x320, the image is filled properly now but the distortion is still there. The good news is that it is perfectly in real device. Just having problem in simulator. Also do i need to change all images according to device resolution? Then how can i support all Android device. I saw the link many times you mentioned. It gives 3 different resolutions for iPhone, iPad and iPadhd. How can i support all Android devices?

Comment: That's where the resolution policy comes in. You have to choose a policy that's best fit for your game. Here's a detail information about multi resolutions support - all devices apply: [click me](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Detailed_explanation_of_Cocos2d-x_Multi-resolution_adaptation)

Answer (score 1):

Scale the sprite before adding to layer

```
sprite->setScale(visibleSize.width / sprite->getContentSize().width, visibleSize.height / sprite->getContentSize().height);
```